# Delete records from another table in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables **Transactions** and **TableMaxDateWithZeroRunningTotal**. The tables are linked by the field called **Pupil** present in both tables. Also both tables have a field called **Date**

I want to delete from the table **Transactions** the records with date <= [TableMaxDateWithZeroRunningTotal].[date].
I made the following query:

```
DELETE Transactions.* 
FROM Transactions INNER JOIN TableMaxDateWithZeroRunningTotal ON Transactions.[Pupil Ref] = TableMaxDateWithZeroRunningTotal.[Pupil Ref]
WHERE (((Transactions.Date)<=[TableMaxDateWithZeroRunningTotal].[MaxOfDate]));
```

But I get the error "could not delete from the specified tables".
Why is it and how can I solve this?

Comment: Is `TableMaxDateWithZeroRunningTotal` really a **table**? It sounds like an aggregate query, which would explain the error. -- `Date` is a problematic column name, you could try `[Date]`.

Comment: Options: 1) save query data to a 'temp' table; 2) use DLookup() on query to pull date values into DELETE action; 3) VBA. There is no VBA posted so why do you reference VBA in title and tag?

Comment: @Andre Yes, TableMaxDateWithZeroRunningTotal is a table (this comes from a query that I convert into a table). I have amended into [Date] but it does not help.

Comment: @June7 1) this is achieved with TableMaxDateWithZeroRunningTotal 2) Isn't DLookup slowing down the process instead of linking the two tables by the [Pupil Ref] ? 3) you are right, I have removed this from the title and tags

Comment: I did a test of DELETE with joined tables and it worked. Yes, domain aggregate function slows performance but so does Cartesian product query.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution here https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/use-a-criteria-from-one-table-to-delete-from/e74471ac-f124-473f-b498-b5e646a34935

The following is my code

```
DELETE * 
FROM 
  Transactions 
WHERE 
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 
      * 
    FROM 
      TableMaxDateWithZeroRunningTotal 
    WHERE 
      Transactions.[Date] <= TableMaxDateWithZeroRunningTotal.MaxOfDate 
      and Transactions.[Pupil Ref] = TableMaxDateWithZeroRunningTotal.[Pupil Ref]
  );
```